# Приложение PyQt5 Python как сделать обработчик кнопок если они создаются динамически

Tags: python, pyqt5

Пишу приложение на PyQt5 Python у меня в приложении кнопки создаются динамически, то есть может их быть от одной и до трех, как мне сделать обработчик для них если они выполняют одну функцию?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать, и что у вас не получается..

Answer (score 0):

Что означает "обработчик кнопок" в Вашем случае?
Если кнопка создаётся, а это соответственно объект с id, именем и прочим. Это можно положить в список (например) и оттуда когда надо брать.
А то что они выполняют одну функцию это не важно для обращения к ним.

Comment: Вот мой код: students = list(get_students(headers).keys())
            for i in range(len(students)):
                btn_name = QPushButton(students[i], self)
                self.buttons.addWidget(btn_name)
                self.btn_res.append(f'btn{i + 1}')

Comment: Я вот создал их добавил их в список, дальше мне как с ними работать?

Comment: @Николай если вам действительно нужна помощь - опубликуйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему. Как это сделать - смотрите мой комментарий выше. Пример надо приводить в теле вопроса, а не в комменариях.

Answer (score -1):

Я в своей задаче сделал так: создал объект на форме, а его имя и сам объект записал в словарь.

```
check_box = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self)
check_box.setObjectName(check_box_name)
check_box.setText(f'{check_box_name}')
check_box.setGeometry(x, y, w, h)
check_box.clicked.connect(self.change_status_checkbox)
dict_all_units[check_box_name] = check_box
```

Но тут нужно понимать, что словарь должен быть виден там, где к нему обращаются.
Если его сделать глобальным (это не красиво), то он буде виден отовсюду.